# How to Prevent Unwanted Spam to Contact Form 7

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7, spam

I posted about this on the [Support page for the plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-prevent-unwanted-spam-to-contact-form-7/), but figured I'd post here now, too -- I'm getting a lot of spam from the plugin [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/), and I was wondering what my options were for validating incoming messages for this plugin. **Rather than installing yet another plugin, it would be great if I could do something within `functions.php`, or even something within one of Contact Form 7's php files to prevent this from happening. Is this possible?**

An example of the kind of spam I'm getting would be something like:

`loans for bad credit guaranteed <a href="http:/redacted">loans for people with bad credit</a> online loans bad credit [url=http://redacted[/url]`

I believe there is some kind of cross-site scripting going on in an effort to store third party back links on my site. I tried preventing this with Javascript but realized that wouldn't fix it, and also was told in another post to always validate/secure against spam server-side rather than client-side.

Comment: A good start is to use Contact Form 7 Honeypot (https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-honeypot/) that adds a hidden text field. then human users doesn't see the difference and automatic spamer fill the field and is stopped.

Comment: Thanks -- somebody else suggested Honeypot, too. I kind of wanted to avoid another plugin, but I guess I'll try it out, although I don't think they are entering text in manually. I think it's some kind of script. Would Honeypot still be able to prevent this?

Comment: Should I have posted this to Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact Form 7 has support for Akismet, and reCaptcha; check the docs. Hidden fields are not useful, IMHO; they are still visible in the page source to a 'scraper'. (Neither are 'questions' and some other techniques.)

The only useful thing that I have found is to add some Javascript to the form that senses human interaction: adding functions that look for on-click and/or on-focus of required fields. Bots have a difficult time with JS, although it is possible a targeted-to-your-specific-form spammer might be able to bypass that. But that is a highly-targeted attack.

I wrote a plugin that adds the on-click/on-focus sensing to CF7 forms: "[FormSpammerTrap for Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/formspammertrap-for-contact-form-7/)". The form 'target' is modified to submit to a 'honeytrap' site, unless an on-click/on-focus is sensed on a required field - that resets the form 'target' to normal. A simple shortcode is used on the form to enable my plugins' technique.

This blocks a lot of spammers, but there is no perfect solution. I've found that a combination of techniques: Akismet, reCaptcha, and my technique will catch a lot of (but not all) spam.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll check this out. Trying to find a coded example or to figure out if this is even possible by doing something in `functions.php` or even one of the contact form 7 files -- it's slightly comforting to hear you say that there is no perfect solution, but I've got Akismet and ReCaptcha, and I'm still getting roughly 50 spam messages a day.

Comment: The plugin I wrote has lots of code: settings/info page, finding the right CF object, processing of shortcode, etc. But the main process is to put JS code that changes the 'target' of the form tag when a required field is on-focus/on-click. You are welcome to look into my plugin code if you want to 'roll your own'. A temporary solution is to make a new Contact page with your CF7 form, and delete the old one (or change it to redirect to a honeyhole somewhere). Thanks for the vote/accept. DM me via my https://www.formspammertrap.com site if you have questions.